# React Jest test actions that do fetch to API

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to wire a test for an action that does a fetch. to the remote API.

So far I only saw examples of Jest testing actions that do not do any fetch but rather dispatch an action to the reducer.

How would I go about testing an action that does fetch to API (in this case this is a Node server) but the Node won't be available for the test to run. I guess what needs to happen is to mock this up. How would I go about this? How can I mock the fetch?

```
import { VEHICLE } from './types';
import { API_ADDRESS } from '../config';


const fetchVehicle = ({ endpoint, options, SUCCESS_TYPE }) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: VEHICLE.FETCH });
  return fetch(`${API_ADDRESS}/vehicle/${endpoint}`, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.errors !== undefined) {
            dispatch({ type: VEHICLE.FETCH_ERROR, ...json });
          } else {
            // console.log('action', {...json})
            dispatch({ type: SUCCESS_TYPE, ...json });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => dispatch({
          type: VEHICLE.FETCH_ERROR, errors: [{ msg: error }]
        }));
}


export const fetchAllVehicles = ({ limit, skip }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: '?limit=' + limit + '&skip=' + skip,
  options: { credentials: 'include' },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS
});


export const fetchVehicleId = ({ id }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: `${id}`,
  options: { credentials: 'include' },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_ID_SUCCESS
});


export const deleteVehicleId = ({ id }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: `${id}`,
  options: {
    method: 'DELETE',
    options: { credentials: 'include' },
  },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_DELETE_SUCCESS
});


export const addNewVehicle = ({ vehicle }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: '',
  options: {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ ...vehicle }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: 'include'
  },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_ADD_SUCCESS
});


export const updateVehicle = ({ vehicle }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: `${vehicle.id}`,
  options: {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify({ ...vehicle }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: 'include'
  },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_UPDATE_SUCCESS
});


export const fetchAllLockedVehicles = ({ limit, skip }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: 'locked/?limit=' + limit + '&skip=' + skip,
  options: { credentials: 'include' },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_LOCKED_SUCCESS
});


export const unlockVehicleId = ({ id }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: `unlock/${id}`,
  options: {
    method: 'POST',
    options: { credentials: 'include' },
  },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_UNLOCK_SUCCESS
});


export const fetchVehiclesSearch = ({ search, limit, skip }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: 'search/?search=' + search + '&limit=' + limit + '&skip=' + skip,
  options: { credentials: 'include' },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_SEARCH_SUCCESS
});


export const fetchLockedVehiclesSearch = ({ search, limit, skip }) => fetchVehicle({
  endpoint: '/locked/search/?search=' + search + '&limit=' + limit + '&skip=' + skip,
  options: { credentials: 'include' },
  SUCCESS_TYPE: VEHICLE.FETCH_LOCKED_SEARCH_SUCCESS
});


export const pushVehicleMessage = ({ type, status, message, fields }) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type, 
    status,
    message,
    fields
  });
}


export const resetVehicle = () => dispatch => { 
  dispatch({ type: VEHICLE.RESET, status: 'success' }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, an ideal test would mock the request so that your test is controlled and always behaves the same way.

Also, you have to take into account that, as your code makes an ajax request (that is an asynchronous operation in nature), you'll have to declare your test as async (you can read more about async tests [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)).

As an example, here is how you could test the success case of the `fetchAllVehicles` action creator:

```
it('should get all vehicles', async () => {
    // Mock the global fetch call, returning a promise with a json method and the response data
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        json: () => ({ data: ['vehicle1', 'vehicle2'] })
    });

    // Mock the dispatch method in order to be able to make assertions
    const dispatch = jest.fn();

    // Call the action creator with the values.
    await fetchAllVehicles({
        limit: 10,
        skip: 2
    })(dispatch);

    // Assert that the dispatch method was called with the correct values.
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        type: VEHICLE.FETCH
    });
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        type: VEHICLE.FETCH_ALL_SUCCESS,
        data: ['vehicle1', 'vehicle2']
    });
});
```